# How to round the numbers up to the third digit?

Tags: numbers, racket, rounding, digits

I havent found a solution for my code to round the outcome numbers up to the 3rd digit. For example: 1,235

```
  (round (/ (* (cpu-clock cpu) (cpu-cores cpu)) (cpu-price cpu)))
```

I found this in a tutorial but I expect a same solution for a decimal integer. How can I do it?

```
(real->decimal-string n [decimal-digits]) → string?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple language-agnostic solution is to multiply by 10^digits before rounding, and then divide again after. So if you want to keep 3 digits, multiply by 1000:

```
round(number * 1000) / 1000
```

If the number is `1.23534`, it gets multiplied to `1235.34`, rounded to `1235`, and then divided back down to the answer you hope for: `1.235`